# How to manage, sort, and filter large numbers of flows in Apache NiFi?

Tags: canvas, apache-nifi, dataflow

Apache Nifi only gives you one canvas per instance. This doesn't lend itself well to managing hundreds of flows. A table view, where flows could be sorted and filtered would allow for better management of large numbers of flows.

Is there anything like that in Nifi that I'm missing? Or planned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently not a data-focused view of all flows in Apache NiFi. For administrative overview like you are describing, I think the best method today is to name the flows uniquely via *Process Groups* and use the search function in the top right of the UI to quickly jump to a specific flow. Nesting process groups will allow you to put logical boundaries around your individual flows.

You can also use *Reporting Tasks* or even a separate NiFi flow to export data about the flows on the canvas to a reporting tool that makes more sense, like Solr, Elasticsearch, etc. in conjunction with a visualization tool like Kibana. By exercising the NiFi API, you can obtain near realtime information about the state of your system.

For the table-based overview of the flows on the canvas, I would suggest you open a feature request Jira [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel).